# C++ bool expression as function argument calls wrong overload

Tags: c++, overloading

In the test program below, calling the `checkit` method with a bool predicate instead calls the integer overload.  Why?

`(i == 10)` should create a boolean value, which should then trigger the bool overload to be called, no?

**Program Output**

```
should be int
  I'm a bool 1
should be bool
  I'm a bool 1
should also be bool
  I'm a int 1
```

**Source**

```
class Overload
{
public:
    void checkIt(bool n) { printf("  I'm a bool %d\n", n);  }
    void checkit(long n) { printf("  I'm a long %ld\n", n); }
    void checkit(int n ) { printf("  I'm a int %d\n", n); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Overload obj;

    int i = 10;
    bool b = true;

    printf("should be int\n");
    obj.checkIt(i);

    printf("should be bool\n");
    obj.checkIt(b);

    printf("should also be bool\n");
    obj.checkit( (i == 10) );
}
```

**EDIT**

Duh!  sorry for the typo.

However, after fixing typo and *commenting out the bool method*, the int method is called with the bool predicate. Is there a default conversion from bool to int if a more appropriate signature is not found?  Strictly speaking, there is no `bool` signature so I was expecting either a compile or runtime error...

**Updated Code**

```
class Overload
{
public:
    //void checkIt(bool n) { printf("  I'm a bool %d\n", n);  }
    void checkIt(long n) { printf("  I'm a long %ld\n", n); }
    void checkIt(int n ) { printf("  I'm a int %d\n", n); }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Overload obj;

    int i = 10;
    bool b = true;

    printf("should be int\n");
    obj.checkIt(i);

    printf("should be bool\n");
    obj.checkIt(b);

    printf("should also be bool\n");
    obj.checkIt( (i == 10) );
}
```

**Updated Output**

```
should be int
  I'm a int 10
should be bool
  I'm a int 1
should also be bool
  I'm a int 1
```

Comment: You have only one overload of a function named `checkIt`, so that's the only one that can possibly be called. There are two unrelated overloads of a function with a different name, `checkit`.

Comment: Looks like a typo. Changing all of the `checkit` to `checkIt` gets the expected result.

Comment: Yes, there's a standard conversion from `bool` to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

`checkIt` isn't overloaded; there's only a `bool` version.

`checkit` is overloaded; there's a `long` and an `int` version.

Your code calls `checkIt` twice and `checkit` once.

Comment: The other way round: one `checkIt`, two `checkit`s

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Edited.

Comment: Thanks melphomene, you saved my sleep, i thought it was going crazy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that function names (and almost everything else) in C++ are CaSe SeNsItIvE.
In your updated code, there are 2 `checkIt` methods, one for `int` type and one for `long` type. You called `checkIt` 3 times, and the 2 last times you passed to the method a `bool` value. In C++ `bool` value automatically casts to `int` with `true == 1` and `false == 0`

```
bool a = 1 // equals to true
bool b = 0 // equals to false
```

As there are no methods accepting 'bool' type, the value automatically casts to `int` and calls the `int` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes C++ uses implicit conversion.bool,char is automatically converted into int /short/long or vice versa.